# Call function Func<string,T>

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have the following function. I would like to call and convert a string to int32. How to do I call this function?

static Func GetConverter(T example)

```
  static Func<string, T> GetConverter<T>(T example)
            {
                return (x) => Convert<T>(x);
            }
```

This is the code used for converting. I got this code from StackOverflow but not sure how to use.

```
static T Convert<T>(string val)
    {
        Type destiny = typeof(T);

        // See if we can cast           
        try
        {
            return (T)(object)val;
        }
        catch { }

        // See if we can parse
        try
        {
            return (T)destiny.InvokeMember("Parse", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch { }

        // See if we can convert
        try
        {
            Type convertType = typeof(Convert);
            return (T)convertType.InvokeMember("To" + destiny.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch { }

        // Give up
        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: You already know target type (int), so why don't you use int.Parse or int.TryParse methods instead?

Comment: I need to create a dynamic data type converter. as for now I know its string to int. But later i want it to work dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must to use GetConverter method, you should first call it to get converter function.

Assuming GetConverter is under class named A:

```
int value = 0;
var converter = A.GetConverter(value);
```

then you can call the converter from GetConverter method like a local function:

```
value = converter("123");
```

I think you don't have to pass a parameter to GetConverter function. This implementation is better since you dont use example parameter:

```
static Func<string, T> GetConverter<T>()
{
    return (x) => Convert<T>(x);
}
```

So now you can use it like:

```
var converter = A.GetConverter<int>();
int value = converter("123");
```

PS: You can use int.TryParse method instead if you know the target (int) and source (string) types. Or you can use the converter function itself without getting another function to wrap it, like: Convert< int >("123")